# R - Query a pair of columns for a given pair

Tags: r, search

I have a dataframe with two columns that will act as a primary key for my query. I'd like to extract a row that contains a pair of identifiers of interest, and get the associated value. For example

```
df <- t(combn(LETTERS, 2))
df <- data.frame(term1 = df[,1], term2 = df[,2], value = sample(10, nrow(df), T))
```

If I want to, say get the value for the pair "C" and "Z", then the only way I can think of doing so, would be

```
cz <- intersect(union(which(df[,1] == "C"), which(df[,2] == "C")), union(which(df[,1] == "Z"), which(df[,2] == "Z")))
df[cz,]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? My dataframe has about 50,000 rows, and I need to perform this operation at least a few million times. So I'd like to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Do you care about the order of the values in your pair? For example, are you looking only for rows where `term1=="C"` and `term2=="Z"`, or are you also looking for rows where `term1=="Z"` and `term2=="C"`?

Comment: No I don't care about the order. Doesn't matter whether C occurs in term1 or term2, and same for Z

Comment: Then I think `df[((df$term1=="C" & df$term2=="Z") | (df$term1=="Z" & df$term2=="C")),]$value` should work? Or, as a function, `function(x,y) { df[((df$term1==x & df$term2==y) | (df$term1==y & df$term2==x)),]$value }`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is this faster than my way? Is there maybe a way I can rearrange the rows of the dataframe to make it faster to search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about speed, data.table should be faster. If you're like me and aren't familiar with data.table syntax, dtplyr makes it easy. In the below benchmarks, dtplyr looks like it's about 3-5x faster than the base R option above. And, to me at least, it's easier to read.

```
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(microbenchmark)

# Creating our test table
df <- tibble(
  term1 = sample(LETTERS, 50000, replace = T),
  term2 = sample(LETTERS, 50000, replace = T),
  value = sample(10, 50000, T)    
)

# lazy version of the test table is for dtplyr
df_lazy <- lazy_dt(df)

# answer proposed above
cz <- intersect(union(which(df[,1] == "C"), which(df[,2] == "C")), union(which(df[,1] == "Z"), which(df[,2] == "Z")))
df[cz,]

# a dtplyr answer
cz_dtplyr <- df_lazy %>%
  filter((term1 == "C" & term2 == "Z") | (term1 == "Z" & term2 == "C"))

#benchmarking the 2 options
benchmarks <- microbenchmark(
  "base_union" = intersect(union(which(df[,1] == "C"), which(df[,2] == "C")), union(which(df[,1] == "Z"), which(df[,2] == "Z"))),
  "dtplyr" = df_lazy %>%
    filter((term1 == "C" & term2 == "Z") | (term1 == "Z" & term2 == "C"))
)

benchmarks

Unit: microseconds
       expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
 base_union 1669.9 1703.15 2127.677 1755.45 2046.40 6121.8   100
     dtplyr  666.8  692.70  744.486  722.10  779.65 1042.2   100
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out tomorrow, and let you know. But it looks like this is what I needed.